# How to use python regex library to find date and time from a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Given a text :

`start_KA03MM7155_RKMS121MI4-4.21005_NEW_end, 2018-01-02 09:48:23`.

How do i extract `2018-01-02` as `020118` in a variable and `09:48:23` as `094823` in another variable using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your date in the string follows YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD pattern, 
code to extract date field

```
import re
text = 'start_KA03MM7155_RKMS121MI4-4.21005_NEW_end, 2018-01-02 09:48:23'
result = re.search('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', text).group(0)
print('result: ', result)
```

`result: 2018-01-02`
then you can manipulate string to get desired output, for your case

```
split_data = d.split('-') #split the string
date_pattern = split_data[-1] + split_data[-2] + split_data[-3][-2:]
print('date Pattern: ', date_pattern)
```

`date Pattern: 020118`
with a small change in regex pattern you can time

```
time_pattern = re.search('(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', a).group(0).replace(':', '')
print('time_pattern: ', time_pattern)
```

`time_pattern: 094823`
**Brief Explanation:**
`\d` looks for digits
`\d{4}` matches 4 digits
`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` looks for a group having (4 digits)-(2 digits)-(2 digits)
to know more about regex you can follow the [official link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 2):

Quick and ***dirty*** way,

```
date = re.sub('-', '', re.findall('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}',a)[0]) # '20180102'
time = re.sub(':', '', re.findall('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',a)[0]) # '094823'
```